# Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration section 'defaultProxy'

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I am trying to access a windows application (which uses the .NET 2.0 framework) from the share folder. The application connects to a web service.

There is no proxy between the application and the web service (on either the remote machine or on the local machine).

When application tries to access any web method I am getting following error:

> Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration section 'defaultProxy'.

I heard there was a hot fix from Microsoft but didn't find anything on the site.

Please suggest how to resolve the problem.

Comment: As you are running the app from a share, I think you have a code-access permissions. I dont recall the details, but you will probably have to play with CASPOL.

Comment: i have already tried Caspol but didn't work.